# module.exports for functions with multiple puppeteer actions does not work

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have code in file login.js

```
   const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const configpass = require("./config.json");
const login_helper = require("./login_helper");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--no-sandbox"],
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 30
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 })

  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({
    waitUntil: "networkidle0"
  });


  await login_helper.login_function(page, configpass.username, configpass.password);

  await navigationPromise


  await page.waitForSelector('.container > .row > .col-md-4 > p > a')
  await page.click('.container > .row > .col-md-4 > p > a')

  await navigationPromise

  //await browser.close()
})()
```

and i want to create one function in external file with many action just like in file login_helper.js

```
    module.exports = {

    login_function: async (page, username, password) => {
        page.goto('http://quotes.toscrape.com/');

        page.waitForSelector('.container > .row > .col-md-4 > p > a');
        page.click('.container > .row > .col-md-4 > p > a');
        page.waitForSelector('.container #username');
        page.click('.container #username');
        page.type(
            ".container #username", username
        );

        page.waitForSelector('.container #password');
        page.click('.container #password');
        page.type(".container #password", password
        );
        page.waitForSelector('body > .container > form > .btn')
        page.click('body > .container > form > .btn')
        return page;
    }
};
```

I am getting error, why?

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.

tnx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppeteer returns promises. You should call await, otherwise, the control flow will not be as you expected. You expect the code to finish each statement, before continuing with the next, but without await, it will immediately start the next one while the first one has not finished yet.

For example, instead of

```
page.goto('http://quotes.toscrape.com/');
```

try

```
await page.goto('http://quotes.toscrape.com/');
```

In addition, errors will not be handled. That is why you get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` exception. Try to add `await` before all interactions with `page` (for details, check the API, but I think, in your case, every call returns a promise).

Comment: thx it works. Can you pls tell me how to use navigationPromise function in login_helper.js?

Comment: According to the documentation (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions ) it will resolve after a navigation completed, with your options, it will additionally wait until there are no more pending requests, which normally means the page is fully loaded. If you "await" the promise, you gain confidence that the login action that you triggered is completed.